# Birchas Kohanim in the Diaspora

Tags: minhag, eretz-yisrael, birchas-kohanim, chutz-laaretz

Why do we (ashkenazim) not do birchas kohanim in chutz la'aretz (except on yom tov), but in Israel, we do?

Comment: Just a note: Even in Israel, it depends on preicse location. Most famously, I think, there is no daily _birkas kohanim_ in _Tz'fas_.

Comment: Good question.  It is, in fact, even a bitul mitzvat aseh.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I don't think it's a bitul aseh if we don't call them up. It's more comparable to not wearing a tallit katan: you aren't obligated in tzitzit because you aren't wearing a four cornered garment, but we still would rather do the mitzva than not.

Comment: What about Ashkenazic Kohanim at a Sephardic minyan?

Comment: @AdamMosheh That question is asked here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22272/an-ashenazi-kohain-lives-outside-israel-when-it-is-not-yom-tov-can-he-bless-th

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tha Rama in Orach Chaim Siman 128 says we do not do Nesias Kapayim as we are only in proper Simcha on Yom Tov. During the rest of the year, even on Shabbos we are worried about our sustanance and our work.

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=18

Comment: And  in Israel?

Comment: See footnote 164 Mishna Berura

Comment: @GershonGold Can you please add in the part about "footnote 164"? That is an integral part of jake's original question

Comment: And upon which source or precedent did the RaM"A or "those countries" base the founding of such a custom?

Comment: This is an interesting answer but leaves us asking whether the Rama would think that those in Israel are not concerned with their parnassa or perhaps does the Rama also hold in Israel it should only be done on yontiff?