# When did daily birkas kohanim stop?

Tags: history, ashkenazi, chutz-laaretz, birchas-kohanim

The original practice, from what I understand, was that *kohanim* would bless the congregation every day during the *amida* of *shacharis* (and of *musaf* and *n'ila* when they were said, and of *mincha* on a fast day). At some point that changed, so that *Ashk'nazim* outside Israel now do so only on holidays and only during *musaf*. (*S'faradim* do it daily, and the practice in Israel is to do it daily, except in some northern cities of Israel.)

When did this change? That is, when did *Ashk'nazim* outside Israel stop the daily practice? And if *S'faradim* or Israelis also stopped it but later reinstated it, when did those occur?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6265/birchas-kohanim-in-the-diaspora

Answer (score 1):

The Bais Yosef at the end of OC:128 brings a Maharil who discusses it having stopped. He lived 1365-1427, so it's been stopped at least since then.